# Haskell pattern matching concept behind text splitter

Tags: string, haskell, pattern-matching, split

I want to know the pattern matching concept behind this code snippet:

```
 split :: String -> Char -> [String]
 split [] delim = [""]
 split (c:cs) delim
     | c == delim = "" : rest
     | otherwise = (c : head rest) : tail rest
       where
         rest = split cs delim
```

I know that `head` returns the 1st element of the list and `tail` returns the rest. But I still cannot understand the functionality of this. This takes a string and breaks it into a list of strings from a given character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it's clearer in the following form:

```
split [] delim = [""]    -- a list containing only an empty String
split (c:cs) delim = let (firstWord:moreWords) = split cs delim
                     in if c == delim
                           then "" : firstWord : moreWords
                           else (c:firstWord) : moreWords
```

The function traverses the input string, comparing each character with the delimiter. If the current character is not the delimiting character, it is tacked on the front of the first word (which may be empty) resulting from splitting the remainder of the string, if it is the delimiting character, it adds an empty string to the front of the result of splitting the remainder.

For example, the evaluation of `split "abc cde" ' '` proceeds like

```
split "abc cde" ' '
    ~> 'a' == ' ' ? No, next guard
    ~> ('a' : something) : somethingElse
```

where `something` and `somethingElse` will be determined later by splitting the remainder `"bc cde". After looking at the first character, it's been determined that whatever the final result is, its first entry starts with`'a'`. Going on to determine the rest,

```
split "bc cde" ' '
    ~> ('b' : something1) : somethingElse1
       where (something1 : somethingElse1) = split "c cde" ' '
```

So now the first two characters of the first entry of the result are known. Then from the next step it is determined that `something1` starts with `'c'`. Then finally we reach a delimiter, that is the case where the first element of the result is determined without reference to later recursive calls, and only the remainder of the result remains to be found in the recursion.

Another way of formulating the algorithm is (thanks @dave4420 for the suggestion)

```
split input delim = foldr combine [""] input
  where
    combine c rest@(~(wd : wds))
        | c == delim = "" : rest
        | otherwise  = (c : wd) : wds
```

Comment: So adding an empty string to the from splits a string. I mean is that the way strings are separated to a list of strings. .? If the delimiting character is found what would it returns...? as in exapmple will say a string called "abc cde" needed to be separated from space.. then when it has a ' ' it will return  " ","cde" or " cde".. and does head takes in a string list..?

Comment: @Gihan `split "abc cde" ' '` will produce `["abc","cde"]`. I'm not sure I understand your next question, but if I do: `head` takes a list of any type, in `split` it is called on a list of `String`s indeed.

Comment: Yeah thats true. About the next question its like this. Will say that the string I want to split is `"abc cde"` as this have 7 characters this has 7 recursion stages right. will start from the final stage. It will return `"E"` . 6th recur wil return `E:F:Null` as in `"EF"`. 5th one will return `D:E:F`  as in `"DEF"`. then comes the space in 4th level. Then it will be `"":"DEF"` right. So this is where the question comes up. Will it be returned from there as a `("","DEF")` or `"DEF"`...?

Comment: Then again if it is `("","DEF")`, in the 3rd level it self will be `C:"":"DEF"` returning `"C","","DEF"` right..?

Comment: I've expanded my answer, maybe that makes it sufficiently clear (if not, ask again).

Comment: Ya got it bro. i was thinking backward. Thanks for the help. Really appreciate it. Only one more thing, why do we use " " an empty string. What is the specialty of it..?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Each (finite and fully [spine] defined) list ends with an empty list `[]`. Whenever a delimiter (or the end of input) is reached, an empty list (of `Char`s, an empty `String`) is inserted to mark the end of one chunk.